# Linux shell script : make a folder with the current date name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a simple backup script and i have problem creating a folder with the curent date for name

My script is that and basically the problem is on the last line

```
drivers=$(ls /media/)

declare -i c=0
for word in $drivers
do
    echo "($c)$word"
    c=c+1
done

read -n 1 drive
echo

c=0
for word in $drivers
do
    if [ $c -eq $drive ]
    then
        backuppath="/media/$word/backup"
    fi
    c=c+1
done


echo "doing back up to $backuppath"

cp -r /home/stefanos/Programming $backuppath/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)
```

Ouput:

```
(0)0362-BA96
(1)Data
(2)Windows
0
doing back up to /media/0362-BA96/backup
cp: cannot create directory `/media/0362-BA96/backup/2012-12-05-21:58:37': Invalid argument
```

The path is triply checked that is existing until /media/0362-BA96/

**SOLVED**:
    Did what janisz  said   the final script looks like

```
drivers=$(ls /media/)

declare -i c=0
for word in $drivers
do
    echo "($c)$word"
    c=c+1
done

read -n 1 drive
echo

c=0
for word in $drivers
do
    if [ $c -eq $drive ]
    then
        backuppath="/media/$word/backup"
    fi
    c=c+1
done
echo "doing back up to $backuppath"

backup(){
  time_stamp=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)
  mkdir -p "${backuppath}/${time_stamp}$1"
  cp -r "${1}" "${backuppath}/${time_stamp}$1"

  echo "backup complete in $1"
}

#####################The paths to backup####################

backup "/home/stefanos/Programming"
backup "/home/stefanos/Android/Projects"
backup "/home/stefanos/Dropbox"
```

Comment: Does `/media/0362-BA96/backup` exist though?

Comment: yes  the backup folder exist in 0362-BA96 , but even if it wasn't it would created automatically right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:` is not valid on FAT (it is used to specify disk). Some of M$ invalid character works on GNU/Linux systems but it is safer to avoid them (just replace with `.`). Use following date format

```
date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S
```

It should works on most file systems but it could be too long for MS DOS FAT. More info you will find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename).

Answer (score 19):

Trying changing it to:

```
time_stamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)
mkdir -p "${backuppath}/${time_stamp}"
cp -r /home/stefanos/Programming "${backuppath}/${time_stamp}"
```

Comment: Is `:` valid character? When I use tab autocomplete it's escaping with `\`

Comment: again :  mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/0362-BA96/backup/2012-12-05-22:13:43': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory `/media/0362-BA96/backup/2012-12-05-22:13:43': Invalid argument
  I forgot to say that its not warking only in the 0362-BA96 device witch is a usb  , is that a problem?

Comment: @SteveL try it on another directory eg `/tmp/`.

Comment: @janisz  yes its working on tmp  creating the date folder etc . Even works  if i just right in the terminal cp somefile /media/0362-BA96/backup/  so the usb drive its ok and there is not any problem with it, its just dosent work in the srcipt

Comment: @SteveL Try avoid any character that could be invalid. Remove all `-` and `:` from  file name. What is device file system?

Comment: @janisz  yep it seems i cant create files with the char :  in the usb (something to do with fat maybe)  i only can create them in the other drives with ext and ntfs